# Compiling code on 10.8 with features of 10.9

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks, osx-mountain-lion

I am using the following lines in my code.

```
EKAuthorizationStatus   authorizationStatus= [EKEventStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
```

Now the above lines is available only in 10.9 + . How can let the code compile in 10.8 system ? In runtime i will surround the above checks with OS version. I need something that will block the code in a 10.8 system during compilation.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

By using the 10.9 SDK.  As long as SDK >= Deployment Target then it will be fine and the host system used during development is not important.

Comment: will something like this not work #if MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_9

Comment: @BadLuckBrian Well that constant is used to define what version of OSX the app will run on.  You *can* use that to build with a lower version of the SDK, but of course the new APIs won't be used.